# Keep my code running in the background on one browsertab

Tags: javascript

I have code that is supposed to run in the background doing a countdown, and the count down is being shown in a modal.

When switching tabs the countdown stops, and my code on the first tab is not being executed anymore.
How can I keep my code running in the background?

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make setInterval also work when a tab is inactive in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome and other browsers have some restrictions on JavaScript running in an inactive tab (low priority, timeout interval must be > 1000 ms, etc., etc.).
The best advice I can give you is to **not rely entirely on timer** (`setInterval()`, `setTimeout()`) to update your JavaScript timer.

If you would record the starting timestamp of your timer:

```
const currentDate = new Date();
const timerStart = currentDate.getTime(); // return date in milliseconds from 1 Jan 1970
```

then you'll be able to calculate the time elapsed at any time when you'll back to your tab, without relying on execution priority for idle tabs behavior across all browsers.